# Login form needs refresh after successful login in order to see admin content

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the content of my index.php. When I tested this on my localhost it works as intended. Once the user submits the username and password, the page refreshes, and a new page is displayed. When I uploaded to my server for some reason when login goes through, a page is loaded with only the header. If the back button is pressed or the refresh button is clicked the html that was supposed to show up after the login does show up. Any idea why it doesn't work immediately after the login is successful and the user is redirected to the same page? Here's my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('header.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
//display index
?>
<div id="inner-wrap">
    <div class="page_title" onclick="window.location = 'index.php';">Admin</div>

    <div class="admin">
        <div class="admin_sec">
        <u>Manage Works</u><br>
        <a href="img_upload.php">upload image</a><br>
        <a href="img_delete.php">delete image</a>
        </div>

        <div class="admin_sec">
        <u>Manage Bio</u><br>
        <a href="bio_edit.php">edit bio</a>
        </div>

        <div class="admin_sec">
        <u>Manage Blog</u><br>
        <a href="../blog/wp-login.php">login to blog</a>
        </div>

        <div class="admin_sec">
        <u>Manage Links</u><br>
        <a href="link_add.php">add link</a><br>
        <a href="link_delete.php">delete link</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="logout">
        <div class="page_title" onclick="window.location='logout.php';">Logout</div>    
    </div>
 </div> 
  </body>
 </html>
 <?php
} else {
//display login
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
        $error = 'All fields are required.';        
    } else {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->bindValue(2, $password);

        $query->execute();

        $num = $query->rowCount();

        if ($num == 1) {
            //user entered correct details
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            //user entered incorrect username and/or password
            $error = 'The username and/or password are incorrect.';
        }
    }
}
?>

<div id="inner-wrap">
<div class="page_title" onclick="window.location = 'index.php';">Login</div>
<div class="admin_sec"> 
    <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login">
    </form>

    <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
        <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo $error; ?></small>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Try posting your header.php file and also  try using double quotes in your header("Location: index.php")

Comment: neither of those things worked. thanks for trying though

Comment: try to put the includes before the session_start(); include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('header.php'); sesion_start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest fix is to place the log-in logic first.

```
session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('header.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
//display login
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
                $error = 'All fields are required.';        
        } else {
                $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");
                $query->bindValue(1, $username);
                $query->bindValue(2, $password);

                $query->execute();

                $num = $query->rowCount();

                if ($num == 1) {
                        //user entered correct details
                        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                } else {
                        //user entered incorrect username and/or password
                        $error = 'The username and/or password are incorrect.';
                }
        }
}
}
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
//display index
?>
<div id="inner-wrap">
        <div class="page_title" onclick="window.location = 'index.php';">Admin</div>

        <div class="admin">
                <div class="admin_sec">
                <u>Manage Works</u><br>
                <a href="img_upload.php">upload image</a><br>
                <a href="img_delete.php">delete image</a>
                </div>

                <div class="admin_sec">
                <u>Manage Bio</u><br>
                <a href="bio_edit.php">edit bio</a>
                </div>

                <div class="admin_sec">
                <u>Manage Blog</u><br>
                <a href="../blog/wp-login.php">login to blog</a>
                </div>

                <div class="admin_sec">
                <u>Manage Links</u><br>
                <a href="link_add.php">add link</a><br>
                <a href="link_delete.php">delete link</a>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="logout">
                <div class="page_title" onclick="window.location='logout.php';">Logout</div>    
        </div>
 </div> 
    </body>
 </html>
 <?php
}else{?>
<div id="inner-wrap">
<div class="page_title" onclick="window.location = 'index.php';">Login</div>
<div class="admin_sec"> 
        <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login">
        </form>

        <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
                <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo $error; ?></small>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. And was most simple. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `header(Location: index.php)` to `header(Location: ./index.php)`this should resolve your issue